# data porting in mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding

While porting data from one mysql database to another there have come some issues like appostrophes have been converted into â€ in a field called story.  Why did this happen and  what should I do now to correct the new database?

I have only the phpmyadmin access of the two databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the charatersets used by your database. You can do this by entering `\s` in the MySQL client. Example output is:

```
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
```

What charactersets do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: what to do if any of the charactertic has different encoding ?

Comment: i have only the phpmyadmin access of the two database

Comment: @silverkid: Are you using the import-function from phpMyAdmin? If yes, then choose the correct encoding (the one from where the data is coming) there.